# how to use ldap authentication with permission taken from db without needing password in UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to do ldap authentication in spring boot security but take roles and other information ( like user region ) from a db.

I came up to a UserDetaisContextMapper impl like:

```
@Component
public class UserDetailsContextMapperImpl implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        UserDetails userWithRoles = userService.enhanceWithRoles(username, new String((byte[]) ctx.getObjectAttribute("userPassword")));
        return userWithRoles;

    }

    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {

    }
}
```

This component is being used like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class LdapSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsContextMapperImpl userDetailsContextMapperImpl;

    public LdapSecurityConfig(UserDetailsContextMapperImpl userDetailsContextMapperImpl) {
        this.userDetailsContextMapperImpl = userDetailsContextMapperImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        var cs = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                "ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org");
        cs.afterPropertiesSet();

        var manager = new LdapUserDetailsManager(cs);

        manager.setUsernameMapper(new DefaultLdapUsernameToDnMapper("ou=groups",
                "uid"));

        manager.setUserDetailsMapper(userDetailsContextMapperImpl);

        manager.setGroupSearchBase("ou=groups");

        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

In the UserDetailsContextMapperImpl  I am forced to pass the password to the service because you can't construct a UserDetail with an empty password.

But I find this to be a hack, because I don't need the password since I know that the authentication succeeded.

What can I do in order to use LDAP authentication but don't care about the password and retrieve the roles from a user repository ?